# Multiple instances of same application with same group id kafka

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

What happens when multiple instances of one application having same consumer group id listen to Kafka topic?

Will the same message be read by both instances or different?

Inside consumer group there are multiple consumer...
But what happens when we have multiple consumer group with same I'd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The topic partitions are distributed across the consumers. A message will only be received by one instance - that which is allocated the partition containing the message.